# Need help finding a wholesale pricing solution based on discounting list price rather than marking up cost

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module

I am about ready to launch a new M2 store and the website will have two stores. One for retail sales and one for dealer sales. I need to be able to set the pricing in the dealer store to be based on discounting MSRP (list price) rather than a discount off of normal pricing or off of cost. For example, brand X, we receive 48% off of MSRP. For dealers, we sell at 35% off MSRP. Retail price is 20% off list. So everything revolves around list price. Are there any off the shelf modules out there that do this? I have been searching in vain and come up empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one's a two-step process. You need to first divide up your customers into customer groups: one for general public, one for dealers.

At that point, you can set Advanced Pricing when setting up or editing a product, giving each a different price.

If that sounds like a long manual process for an existing catalog, it is. I've not heard of any third-party extensions to automate it, but the options exist to make it very possible. This is especially true for new items being added to the catalog once the setup is done.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, that is definitely very labor intensive. I figured I'm going to have to have a module custom coded to do this.